Error (Xcode): unable to attach DB: error: accessing build database "/Build/Intermediates.noindex/XCBuildData/build.db"
Flutter Doctor
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.24.5, on macOS 15.1.1 24B91 darwin-arm64, locale
tr-TR)
• Flutter version 3.24.5 on channel stable at
/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/flutter/3.24.3/flutter
• Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
• Framework revision dec2ee5c1f (2 weeks ago), 2024-11-13 11:13:06 -0800
• Engine revision a18df97ca5
• Dart version 3.5.4
• DevTools version 2.37.3
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
• Android SDK at /Users/emircancoskun/Library/Android/sdk
• Platform android-35, build-tools 34.0.0
• Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home/bin/java
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.6+0-17.0.6b829.9-10027231)
• All Android licenses accepted.
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 16.1)
• Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
• Build 16B40
• CocoaPods version 1.16.2
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
• Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome
[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.3)
• Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
• Flutter plugin can be installed from:
 https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
• Dart plugin can be installed from:
 https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.6+0-17.0.6b829.9-10027231)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.95.3)
• VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
• Flutter extension version 3.100.0
[✓] Connected device (5 available)
• iphone (2) (mobile)             • 00008030-000C2C302242202E            • ios            • iOS 18.1.1 22B91
• iPhone 16 Pro Max (mobile)      • A232990F-DB11-4648-B5CB-46148EBA84DE • ios            •
com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-18-1 (simulator)
• macOS (desktop)                 • macos                                • darwin-arm64   • macOS 15.1.1 24B91
darwin-arm64
• Mac Designed for iPad (desktop) • mac-designed-for-ipad                • darwin         • macOS 15.1.1 24B91
darwin-arm64
• Chrome (web)                    • chrome                               • web-javascript • Google Chrome
131.0.6778.86
[✓] Network resources
• All expected network resources are available.
• No issues found!
There are 3 flutter files on the computer, 2 of them run the iOS application, but I get this error in 1 of them. Thanks in advance for your help

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
